# Can't access Ionic from browser while using docker

Tags: node.js, docker, ionic-framework

i'm trying to access localhost:8100 which is my ionic app that's running inside a docker container but it won't open.
Here is my dockerfile :

```
FROM node:10.16.3


WORKDIR /usr/src/ionic-app


COPY ./ /usr/src/ionic-app

RUN npm install -g cordova ionic
RUN npm install
```

And here is my Docker-compose file 
version: '3.6'

services:

```
  #Backend API
  backend-api:
    container_name: backend
    build:
      context: ./api/
    working_dir: /usr/src/smart-brain-api
    command: npm run debug
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      REDIS_HOST: redis
      MONGOOSE_URI: 'mongodb://mongo:27017/appcomdill'
    links:
      - mongo
      - redis

  #MongoDB
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    environment:
      MONGOOSE_URI: 'mongodb://mongo:27017/appcomdill'
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"

  #Redis
  redis:
    container_name: redis
    environment:
      REDIS_HOST: redis
    image: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"

  #Ionic Front-end
  ionic:
    container_name: front-end
    build:
      context: ./ionic
    working_dir: /usr/src/ionic-app
    command: ionic serve
    ports:
      - "8100:8100"
```

Every time i try to connect to http://localhost:8100/ it keeps on giving me "localhost didn't send any data"

Comment: Can you share the logs of your ionic container?

Comment: Have you tried to EXPOSE 8100 in your dockerfile ? This is apart from the binding in your docker-compose.yml

Comment: @CristianCordova the console logs are empty for some reason :/ .

Comment: @BrianDucca still not working

Comment: What about the logs of the docker build process of your ionic image? And trying to run your ionic image with a similar command such as **docker run -p 8100:8100 my_ionic_image**

Comment: I am still getting "This site can’t be reached172.22.0.2 took too long to respond. Try: Checking the connection Checking the proxy and the firewall ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT"

Answer (score 8):

Try changing your command to `ionic serve --external`

Comment: It works!! I search a lot for a solution like that, thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

As [Joseph](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60230759/7035616) mentioned you can fix that by specifying the --external option

This explained in ionic [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/serve):

By default, ionic serve boots up a development server on localhost. To serve to your LAN, specify the --external option, which will use all network interfaces and print the external address(es) on which your app is being served.